# How to remove a recurring character from a column?

Tags: awk

I have data:

```
33305:1      0.045 
33406:1      0.432  
22294:1      0.345
28364:1      0.354
```

And I want to remove the `:1` from column 1 in every row; would I use gsub for this?

Comment: Is it the text `:1`, or is it "colon then a single-digit number", or is it "the last two characters"?

Comment: It is the text :1 as in this example this occurs at the end on every row

Comment: If any of the existing answers solved your problem, please don't forget to indicate so with the checkmark next to it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

To replace a single `:1` in field 1:

```
awk '{sub(":1", "", $1); print}' < input
```

To delete the last two characters from field 1, regardless of what they are:

```
awk '{$1=substr($1, 1, length($1)-2); print}' < input
```

The [gsub](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) function would replace *every* instance of the string; since your sample input only has one such string, using sub would be equivalent to using gsub.

Answer (score 4):

For your simple case - ***sed*** would be enough:

```
sed 's/:1//' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Small variation on the theme of `awk` with sub - use `:` as separator for fields, and that will make `1    0.045` a column 2. Now all you have to do is get rid of the leading character

```
$ awk -F':' '{sub(/^[[:digit:]]/," ",$2);print}' input.txt                  
33305        0.045 
33406        0.432  
22294        0.345
28364        0.354
```